# Get date added of Finder items in Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I can get files by date modified using this bit of code:

```
        get (files of entire contents of folder "Macintosh HD:General Music:05 Reggae:" whose modification date is less than ((current date)) - modDate * days)
```

but I can't seem to get their date added (nor is it listed in Applescript dictionary for Finder that I can see). This is weird, 'cause I can do a smart folder that uses this property.

Any idea on how to get files who were added within 15 days? Otherwise I'm doing loads of weird stuff with GUI at the moment and I'd like to automate it further.

Thanks

Tardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search Spotlight's metadata with the `mdfind` command, use the **kMDItemDateAdded** key:

```
set _15daysAgo to -15 * days -- number of seconds
set tFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of "Macintosh HD:General Music:05 Reggae:"
-- find files, not folders
do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & tFolder & " 'kMDItemDateAdded>$time.now(" & _15daysAgo & ") && ! kMDItemContentType == public.folder'"
set tFiles to paragraphs of the result
repeat with i in tFiles
    tell i to set contents to i as POSIX file as alias
end repeat
tFiles -- list of files who were added within 15 days
```

---

Or, use the methods of the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html) Class to get the `NSURLAddedToDirectoryDateKey` of the files (require **Yosemite** or **El Capitan**),

Here's the AppleScript:

```
set _15daysAgo to -15 * days -- number of seconds
set f to POSIX path of "Macintosh HD:General Music:05 Reggae:"

do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'import sys; from Foundation import NSFileManager, NSURL, NSDate, NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
def procFolder(tDir):
    p = dfM.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL_includingPropertiesForKeys_options_error_(tDir, myKeys, NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles, None)[0]
    for f in p:
        myDict, error=f.resourceValuesForKeys_error_(myKeys, None)
        if error is None:
            if (myDict.get(\"NSURLIsDirectoryKey\")): procFolder(f)
            elif (myDict.get(\"NSURLAddedToDirectoryDateKey\").compare_(d) == 1):
                print f.path().encode(\"utf8\")

fold=NSURL.fileURLWithPath_isDirectory_(sys.argv[1].decode(\"utf8\"), True)
dfM=NSFileManager.defaultManager()
d=NSDate.dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow_(" & _15daysAgo & ")
myKeys=[\"NSURLIsDirectoryKey\", \"NSURLAddedToDirectoryDateKey\"]
procFolder(fold)' " & f

set tFiles to paragraphs of the result
repeat with i in tFiles
    tell i to set contents to i as POSIX file as alias
end repeat
tFiles -- list of  files who were added within 15 days
```